# Jenkins slave not stable using jnlp connection

Tags: jenkins, jnlp, jenkins-agent

I have small Jenkins Environment of 2 windows servers ( Master and Slave ) .
I want to configure the Slave as a windows service .

while the `"java -jar agent.jar -workDir "C:\JENKINS""` command working and getting the Slave running.The Launch agent from browser getting started and looping from connected to Terminated over and over again .
on the jenkins i see the errors :

> Ping response time is too long or timed out.
>
> Connection was broken

and :

> java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException  at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ChannelApplicationLayer.onReadClosed(ChannelApplicationLayer.java:209)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ApplicationLayer.onRecvClosed(ApplicationLayer.java:222)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.onRecvClosed(ProtocolStack.java:832)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.FilterLayer.onRecvClosed(FilterLayer.java:287)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.onRecvClosed(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:181)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.switchToNoSecure(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:283)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.processWrite(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:503)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.processQueuedWrites(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:248)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.doSend(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:200)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.doCloseSend(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:213)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.doCloseSend(ProtocolStack.java:800)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ApplicationLayer.doCloseWrite(ApplicationLayer.java:173)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ChannelApplicationLayer$ByteBufferCommandTransport.closeWrite(ChannelApplicationLayer.java:314)
>     at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1450)     at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1403)  at
>   jenkins.slaves.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver.afterChannel(DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver.java:173)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpConnectionState$4.invoke(JnlpConnectionState.java:421)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpConnectionState.fire(JnlpConnectionState.java:312)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpConnectionState.fireAfterChannel(JnlpConnectionState.java:418)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpProtocol4Handler$Handler$1.run(JnlpProtocol4Handler.java:334)
>     at
>   jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
>     at
>   jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Connect agent to Jenkins one
>   of these ways:

in the log file i see :

> JNLP agent connected from SERVERMACH/10.10.8.6 Remoting version: 3.20
>   This is a Windows agent Also:
>   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to
>   JNLP4-connect connection from SERVERMACH/10.10.8.6:63232      at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1741)
>         at
>   hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:357)
>         at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:955)       at
>   hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1131)       at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.EnvInjectComputerListener.onOnline(EnvInjectComputerListener.java:158)
>         at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:620)
>         at
>   jenkins.slaves.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver.afterChannel(DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver.java:168)
>         at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpConnectionState$4.invoke(JnlpConnectionState.java:421)
>         at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpConnectionState.fire(JnlpConnectionState.java:312)
>         at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpConnectionState.fireAfterChannel(JnlpConnectionState.java:418)
>         at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpProtocol4Handler$Handler$1.run(JnlpProtocol4Handler.java:334)
>         at
>   jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
>         at
>   jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source) hudson.remoting.ProxyException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field
>   private int java.lang.reflect.Field.modifiers accessible: module
>   java.base does not "opens java.lang.reflect" to unnamed module
>   @7d9a7b14     at
>   java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.service.EnvInjectMasterEnvVarsSetter.call(EnvInjectMasterEnvVarsSetter.java:36)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.service.EnvInjectMasterEnvVarsSetter.call(EnvInjectMasterEnvVarsSetter.java:16)
>     at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)    at
>   hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)  at
>   hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)   at
>   hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:93)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ERROR: Connection terminated
>   java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException  at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ChannelApplicationLayer.onReadClosed(ChannelApplicationLayer.java:209)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ApplicationLayer.onRecvClosed(ApplicationLayer.java:222)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.onRecvClosed(ProtocolStack.java:832)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.FilterLayer.onRecvClosed(FilterLayer.java:287)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.onRecvClosed(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:181)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.switchToNoSecure(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:283)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.processWrite(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:503)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.processQueuedWrites(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:248)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.doSend(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:200)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.doCloseSend(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:213)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.doCloseSend(ProtocolStack.java:800)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ApplicationLayer.doCloseWrite(ApplicationLayer.java:173)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ChannelApplicationLayer$ByteBufferCommandTransport.closeWrite(ChannelApplicationLayer.java:314)
>     at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1450)     at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1403)  at
>   jenkins.slaves.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver.afterChannel(DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver.java:173)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpConnectionState$4.invoke(JnlpConnectionState.java:421)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpConnectionState.fire(JnlpConnectionState.java:312)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpConnectionState.fireAfterChannel(JnlpConnectionState.java:418)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpProtocol4Handler$Handler$1.run(JnlpProtocol4Handler.java:334)
>     at
>   jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
>     at
>   jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Tested :Java Versions, added parameters to the JVM configuration , network connectivity and JNLP port .
Any directions will be great ! 
thanks !

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem? I am running into a similar issue and suspect it has to do with the JNLP port.

Comment: @tdensmore i verified im running on Java 8 and reinstall of the agent and the server helped . not the greatest solution but it helped

Comment: Mine had to do with badly formatted YAML in my pipeline. Since I am running on K8S, the pod failed silently and the connection timed out... the error messages are very bad when dealing with pods and often mask the real problem.